# What is the most common way to unpack a jar file after jenkins maven build?

Tags: maven, build, jenkins

I am new to maven and Jenkins so I do not know what is the most common way to extract the JAR file build by maven in the same Jenkins job.

Running `mvn install` in a Jenkins job outputs the file `/home/user/.jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/project/target/package-2.0.0.jar`.

I want to extract it to some directory like `/opt/project` and call `/opt/project/script.sh`.

I thought of a post-build shell script calling `jar -xvf <path>/package-2.0.0.jar` but how to get the version number (2.0.0) then? Maybe there is a maven goal to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to extract the JAR? Cant you just run the JAR directly?

Comment: if you told us why you need the jar unpacked (what does script.sh do) maybe there's a way to eliminate the need altogether?

Comment: It is a packed web app and inside there are some scripts and configuration files.

Comment: Than you should package the war application via maven-assembly-plugin to a zip/tar.gz archive instead of jar (in particular if it's web application, cause web apps are usually packaged as war archives and **not** as jar archives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define that artifact as a dependency in some other module (the module that will run the shell script) and use the dependency plugin to [unpack it](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

that would mean you'd have (at least) 2 modules in your maven project - one that produces the jar, and the other that does something with the artifact produced by the 1st.

if that doesnt fit your need you could bind the unpack after the install phase (the artifact makes it into the local repository at the install phase, and the dependency plugin only deals with artifacts from the local repository) and do it there.

if youre still not satisfied you can get the artifact name in a maven pom.xml file by using `${project.build.finalName}`. the default is `${artifactId}-${version}` as you can see [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) (look at the super pom). if you need it with the suffix it'll be something like `${artifactId}-${version}.${packaging}`

Answer (score 1):

if you are running on linux based systems something like

```
jar -xvf `ls <path>/package-*.jar`
```

will do the job.